# Detect OS type / compiler with elegant C/C++ code (especially gcc/g++)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operating-system, detection

I know that I can detect a compiler type (for example gcc: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/). But how about g++? Can I use `__GNUC__` macro also for testing if Im using g++?

Another question about OS type. I know, I can do that:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
    /* Linux. --------------------------------------------------- */

#endif
```

But how to make it an elegant solution? Make it as first function in main? I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

int compiler()
{
    #if defined (__GNUC__)
        return 0;
    #elif defined (_MSC_VER)
        return 1;
    #else
        return -1;
    #endif;
}

int os()
{
    #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
        return 0;
    #elif defined(__linux__)
        return 1;
    #else
        return -1;
    #endif
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << compiler() << "\n";
    std::cout << os();
    return 0;
}
```

Is above code elegant, or it can be done better (more portable, etc)?

Comment: Consider http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/ and the implementation of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/config/select_platform_config.hpp

Comment: Possibly you want to do things in a certain manner depending upon the compiler.  The question in it's current form seems pretty vague.